# Overpay state income tax this year to offset federal taxable income to the next year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, california

This year (2016) I am a waged employee and will earn something close to $100K. Next year (2017) I don't plan to work at all so my projected income for 2017 would be $0.

Since the state tax that I paid this year (including the amount I overpaid) is deductible in my 2016 federal tax return. **Wouldn't it make sense to dramatically  overpay state tax this year and then itemize it?**

For example, assuming I would overpay 40K in state taxes this year, then my taxable income for 2016 would be 100K-40K=60K. Next year I would receive from state 1099G form with 40K for which, I assume, I would have to pay tax in 2017, but it would be lower income tax bracket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, they thought of that.

See page 148 of [IRS Pub 17](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p17.pdf):

> **Estimated tax payments.** You can deduct estimated tax payments you made during the year
>   to a state or local government. However, you
>   must have a reasonable basis for making the
>   estimated tax payments. Any estimated state or
>   local tax payments that are not made in good
>   faith at the time of payment are not deductible.

In your case, since your $40K payment far exceeds any reasonable estimate of your actual state tax liability, it wouldn't be deductible.  If you tried to deduct it, it seems like a pretty good bet you'd be audited and have your deduction disallowed, and probably owe civil and/or criminal penalties.

Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/1494/

Comment: So it still makes sense to hedge on the high side, as long as you don't overdo it?

Comment: @Brick: yes....

Comment: What, not this one? https://xkcd.com/1566/